# Krunner crashing after typing 3 letters

Tags: arch-linux, kde, manjaro, plasma

I recently started having an issue where KRunner will crash when I am searching, but only after the 3rd character is entered. I can type, delete and retype up to 2 characters without issue. As soon as I type the third character I get a crash notification. I am using the Plasma 5 desktop version 5.3.1 on Manjaro Linux.

When I run it directly from the command line I get the following output while it is running:

```
Trying to use rootObject before initialization is completed, whilst using setInitializationDelayed. Forcing completion
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Trying to open ksycoca from "/home/tmacey/.cache/ksycoca5"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "org.kde.activities"
QObject::connect: No such signal KActivities::Consumer::serviceStatusChanged(KActivities::Consumer::ServiceStatus)
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'Activities')
org.kde.krunner: Categories not enabled. Removing runner:  "org.kde.activities"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "calculator"
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/tmacey/.qalculate/eurofxref-daily.xml"
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/tmacey/.qalculate/eurofxref-daily.xml"
org.kde.krunner: Categories not enabled. Removing runner:  "calculator"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "Dictionary"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "Dictionary"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "Spell Checker"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "Kill Runner"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "Kill Runner"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "recentdocuments"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "recentdocuments"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "locations"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "locations"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "bookmarks"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "bookmarks"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "baloosearch"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "baloosearch"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "org.kde.datetime"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "org.kde.datetime"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "org.kde.windowedwidgets"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "org.kde.windowedwidgets"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "unitconverter"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "unitconverter"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "windows"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "windows"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "Audio Player Control Runner"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "Audio Player Control Runner"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "webshortcuts"
org.kde.kurlfilter-ikws: ":q"
org.kde.kurifilter-ikws: Keywords Engine: Loading config...
org.kde.kurifilter-ikws: Web Shortcuts Enabled:  true
org.kde.kurifilter-ikws: Default Shortcut:  ""
org.kde.kurifilter-ikws: Keyword Delimiter:  :
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "webshortcuts"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "services"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "services"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "shell"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "shell"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "PowerDevil"
Error contacting the daemon!
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "PowerDevil"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "desktopsessions"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "desktopsessions"
org.kde.krunner: Loading runner:  "places"
org.kde.krunner: Loaded: "places"
org.kde.kactivities.lib.core: Killing the consumer
org.kde.kactivities.lib.core: Killing the consumer
org.kde.kurifilter-shorturi: "k"
org.kde.kurifilter-shorturi: path = "k"  isLocalFullPath= false  exists= false  url=  QUrl( "k" ) 
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Trying to open ksycoca from "/home/tmacey/.cache/ksycoca5"
org.kde.kurifilter-shorturi: "kr"
org.kde.kurifilter-shorturi: path = "kr"  isLocalFullPath= false  exists= false  url=  QUrl( "kr" ) 
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Trying to open ksycoca from "/home/tmacey/.cache/ksycoca5"
org.kde.kurifilter-shorturi: "kru"
org.kde.kurifilter-shorturi: path = "kru"  isLocalFullPath= false  exists= false  url=  QUrl( "kru" ) 
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Trying to open ksycoca from "/home/tmacey/.cache/ksycoca5"
session switching to "kru"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Trying to open ksycoca from "/home/tmacey/.cache/ksycoca5"
Accessed invalid KPluginInfo object
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/bin/krunner from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__1
KCrash: Application 'krunner' crashing...
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__1
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 8 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 11 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 14 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 16 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 24 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 9 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 15 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 12 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 17 and type 'Exception', disabling...
[1]  + 6730 suspended (signal)  krunner
```

I tried disabling all of the plugins, which seems to have prevented any crashes, but I was unable to determine which plugin was causing the issues. If anyone has suggestions on how to get this fixed I would greatly appreciate it as KRunner is a large part of my daily workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the misbehaving plugin turned out to be `windowed widgets`. Once I disabled that plugin in the Krunner settings I no longer experience any crashes. I have not yet determined what it is about that plugin that led to the crash but I will report back if I do.

Comment: This doesn't help. I disabled every plugin except applications and it still crashes.

Comment: How did you figure out that it was `windowed widgets` and how would I got about disabling them?

Answer (score 1):

@G-Man: Sorry, cannot comment below.. rep must be over 50? O.o

Anyway: I solved my problem. I narrowed it down to the folder `~/.local/share/baloo`

When the folder is removed/moved I can search for everything.
When the folder is present it crashes at the second char.
Maybe you have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this seemed to be a problem with baloo indexing, as well. When renaming the folder `~/.local/share/baloo` krunner works fine again.